# Mysql multiple tables select

Tags: mysql

I've got a table, called for example, "node", from which I need to return values for as shown:

```
SELECT nid FROM node WHERE type = "book"
```

After I get a list of values let's say:

```
|**nid**|
|123|
|12451|
|562|
|536|
```

Then I need to take these values, and check another table, for rows where column 'path' has values as "node/123", "node/12451" (numbers the previous request returned) in one joined request. It all would be easier if collumn 'path' had simple numbers, without the 'node/'. 
And then also count the number of identical i.e. 'node/123' returned.
End result would look like:

```
nid |  path  | count(path) | count(distinct path) 
123 |node/123|  412        |       123        
562 |node/562|  123        |       56
```

Works fine if done in multiple separated queries, but that won't do.

Comment: How can `count(distinct path)` be different from 1 for a given nid/path pair?

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.nid from node a join othertable b 
on b.path = concat("node/", a.nid) where type='book'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like the following (`nid` may require additional conversion to some string type):

```
SELECT *
FROM OtherTable
JOIN node ON path = CONCAT('node/', nid)
WHERE type = 'book'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. Basically, the problem was that I didn't know how to get `nid` and `node/` together, but `concat` helped.
End result looks something like:

```
  SELECT node.nid, accesslog.path, count(accesslog.hostname), count(distinct accesslog.hostname)
    FROM `node`, `accesslog`
   WHERE node.uid=1
     AND node.type='raamat' 
     AND accesslog.path = CONCAT('node/', node.nid)
GROUP BY node.nid
```